# Use of Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()

Tags: java

This piece of code is used to set the icon of JFrame

```
this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/Eserver/Dictionaryicon.png")));
```

Here what is the use of Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()

Comment: Have you looked at the [JavaDoc for Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html)?

Comment: I can't access the given page.